# Python - How to plot a function with conditions?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a reflectance curve when light travels from glass to air with Python.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def t_angle(theta):
    n = 1.5
    return np.arcsin(n * np.sin(theta))

def reflection(theta):
    t = t_angle(np.deg2rad(theta))
    up = 1.5 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) - np.cos(t)
    down = 1.5 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) + np.cos(t)
    
    return np.power(up,2)/np.power(down,2)

x = np.arange(0, 90, 0.01)

y1 = reflection(x)

matplotlib.rc('axes.formatter', useoffset=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel=r'Incidence angle', ylabel=r'R')
plt.axis([0, 90, 0, 1])


plt.plot(x, y1, 'r', label='R')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

`t_angle` is a function that calculates the transmission angle, and `reflection` is a function that calculates the reflectance.

The thing is, at `theta = 41.81` deg, `reflection` breaks because its inside will be bigger than 1.

So, I am trying to make `reflection` to return the value 1 if `theta` is bigger or the same as 41.81.

I first thought maybe putting a condition inside `reflection` like below might be the solution:

```
def reflection(theta):
    t = t_angle(np.deg2rad(theta))
    up = 1.5 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) - np.cos(t)
    down = 1.5 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) + np.cos(t)

    if(theta > 41.81):
        return np.power(up,2)/np.power(down,2)
    return 1
```

However the Python console showed the following error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/Users/Desktop/plotting2.py", line 7
    return np.arcsin(n * np.sin(theta))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Users/Desktop/plotting2.py", line 29, in <module>
    y1 = reflection(x)
  File "C:/Users/Users/Desktop/plotting2.py", line 14, in reflection
    if(theta > 41.81):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I had some thought and I thought the error came because x is an array?? But I'm not really sure...

Is there anyway to make the program plot 1 if `reflection` breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the usual calculations and at the end, put `1`s to the output array's entries that correspond to `theta > 41.81` via masking:

```py
def reflection(theta):
    t = t_angle(np.deg2rad(theta))
    up = 1.5 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) - np.cos(t)
    down = 1.5 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) + np.cos(t)

    output = np.power(up,2)/np.power(down,2)
    # mask and fill with 1
    output[theta > 41.81] = 1
    return output
```

To see the effect, you might want to expand top y-axis limit a bit i.e.

```
plt.axis([0, 90, 0, 1.1]) # 1 -> 1.1
```

and we get:

[image: img]

Comment: Oh wow this works!! I didn't know about array masking... Thanks for the advice!!